# Creating a swim lane chart using d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I need to generate a swim lanes chart similar to the following but with the addition of showing dates on the Y-axis. All of the nodes I need to show are activities with dependencies, no flow control elements.

[image: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a5/Approvals.jpg]

Is this possible using something like d3 or is there a better javascript library to use for this type of chart?  I haven't seen any examples like it, so if it is possible using d3 I'm not sure where I would start.  Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Based on the previous answer and comments, I started down the path of implementing the chart using `Raphael.js`.  After writing 600+ lines of code (mostly framework stuff to make up for its bare bones nature) I discovered that `Raphael.js` is extremely slow at rendering text. Not sure exactly why, but it's apparently a known issue. In the end it was taking 3.5s to render a chart with 300 items with 80% of the time spent rendering text.

I then started over with `d3.js`. I found that `d3.js` is the much better choice when creating data bound charts when legacy browser support isn't a concern.  Creating a swim lane chart in `d3.js` took me about 100 lines of code vs the 600+ for Raphael.js.  The `d3.js` version also has more functionality, looks nicer, and is more responsive.

While the declarative style of `d3.js` takes some getting used to, it makes working with data super easy. As an added bonus, my chart now renders in about 250 ms :)

See http://bl.ocks.org/1962173 for the final swim lane chart that I created.

Comment: This is great, and almost what i need as well. My use case is having this work somewhat like Mozilla Butter, where i could add and interact with nodes inside the time line. Example of timeline could be found here https://popcorn.webmaker.org/

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion raphael.js is suitable here. It provides support for all browsers including IE6-8, while d3 works in SVG-enabled browsers only.

Comment: Not sure how this is helpful. OP doesn't mention any browser support requirements.

Comment: I concur.  I have been using Raphael for a little while and I find it to be a very nice tool and the fact that it works all the way down to IE6 is great.

Comment: @Dogbert While nor d3, neither raphael.js have no native support for such type of charts, raphael.js has wider browser support. This is why I recommend it.

Comment: Are there any libraries or examples for raphael that might be useful? Or would I be starting from scratch?