# Neo4j : Adding a swim lane for a graph

Tags: neo4j

I want to create a graph with Neo4j (it is like a flow chart). So there to separate segments, I want to add a swim lane. 
i.e

[image: swimlanes]
<sub>(source: [agilemodeling.com](http://agilemodeling.com/images/style/activityDiagramArchitectureProcess.gif))</sub>

Is this possible with Neo4j?

Comment: Is this the high level of the thing you want to model, or the model itself? Asked another way...are there going to be specific instances of the things you have in each shape, or is this...it? Also, what are the relationships between your nodes? I have a feeling you're looking for an entirely different tool for a use case that neo4j is not made for. Have you read the developer documentation to get a feel for how neo4j is used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neo4j is a Graph Database, and could easily store the representation of the flow chart you link to (you could Label each node with its swimlane for example), but the visualization is something you would have to use another application for (the neo4j browser for example will use a force directed layout).

Some examples of Javascript based libraries that you could look into:

- http://gojs.net/latest/samples/swimlanes.html
- [Creating a swim lane chart using d3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9417218/creating-a-swim-lane-chart-using-d3)

  - http://bl.ocks.org/bunkat/1962173

Answer (score 2):

A graph is data, it's not a chart. The Neo4j browser offers some visualization of that data, but only of the data. It's not that customizable.